# How can I have 100% height nested flex containers in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

```css
.page {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}

.outer {
  background: #f99;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border: 2px solid #099
}

.innerFlex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 // height: 100%;
  background: #a9a;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="innerFlex">
        <div class="item">A</div>
        <div class="item">B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      sdds
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On Firefox 63, it displays as I'd expect with .innerFlex filling 100% of it's parent element's height:

[image: Firefox]

however on Chrome 70 it does not honour the `height: 100%` rule as I'd expect it to:

[image: Chrome]

Why is this and how can I get round it? `.item` cannot have a pre-defined height as it needs to be sized according to it's flex container, which will change in my use case. Thanks!

Note: The questions this was originally marked as a duplicate for are not the same. The first didn't address flexbox, and the second didn't address the difference in behaviour between Chrome and FF.

Comment: The question is: percentage of what? the content is defining the height of parent so how can you define the height based on that?

Comment: Percentage of the computed height. ....and the latter is the question I'm asking ;-)

Comment: you have a cycle, the child is defined with percentage of parent height and height of parent need to be defined with child element .. so? what will be the computed height?

Comment: Set `flex:1` instead of `flex-grow: 1;` on the `.item` selector

Comment: Ah that does actually work! Cheers @vsync !